# Why all dates columns in drupal are type=int and not type=date/timestamp/time?

Tags: database

I want to make this question short, so as title says "Why all dates in drupal are INT" ?

I've notice that in [Schema API](http://drupal.org/node/159605) there was "datetime" but it was removed in D7. 
Also all tables that have time in it (cache_*,semaphore,node etc.) have INT instead of TIMESTAMP.

Before debating "INT vs TIMESTAMP" flame, I would like to remind you that:

- DATETIME is obvious what the value represents.
- INT is smaller
- TIMESTAMP has both advantages.

The thing is that I want to understand what's "philosophy of drupal" for this.

Comment: Because Drupal doesn't just support MySQL as a backend, it also supports backends that do not have a `DATETIME`/`TIMESTAMP` type. If it's a problem see [the docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21schema.inc/group/schemaapi/7) and use one of the db specific types (e.g. `mysql_type`) for your schema

Comment: drupal supports postgres and sqlite. Both have DATETIME...

Comment: Then I would guess their implementations are not uniform across the different DBMSs, and so can't be used generically

Comment: well that's my guess too... Just wanted to be sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the main reason its that you cannot have two columns with TIMESTAMP and default NOW() value in MySQL according the documentation ([see that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267658/having-both-a-created-and-last-updated-timestamp-columns-in-mysql-4-0)). So seems to be the easier way to workaround it its to use int.